# WSO2 Script mediator unable to parse self closing XML tags

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using a script mediator to convert the XML response to a JSON. The mediator works properly if the XML is well formatted but if the XML has self closing tags , it fails..

Any ideas to fix this issue is greatly appreciated..

```
<!-- XML data-->
<getMyClsScheduleResponse >
<RegisteredClass>
  <ClassNumber>10757</ClassNumber>
  <SubjectCode>AAS</SubjectCode>
  <CatalogNumber>510</CatalogNumber>
  <SectionNumber>001</SectionNumber>
  <SectionType>IND</SectionType>
  <SectionTypeDescr>Independent Study</SectionTypeDescr>
  <SessionDescr>Regular</SessionDescr>
  <CourseDescr>Supervised Research</CourseDescr>
  <ClassTopic />
  <CreditHours>1 - 6</CreditHours>
  <LMSURL /> <!--  Self Closing tag -->
  <Meeting>
     <MeetingNumber>1</MeetingNumber>
     <Days />
     <Times />
     <StartDate>09/02/2014</StartDate>
     <EndDate>12/10/2014</EndDate>
     <Location>TBA</Location>
     <TopicDescr />
  </Meeting>
```

```
/** Script Mediator */              
function transformPayload(output) {
payload = output.getPayloadJSON();
results = payload.getMyClsScheduleResponse.RegisteredClasses;
var response = new Array();

var registeredClass = new Array();
for (i=0;i<results.length; i++ ) {
    class_schedule = results[i];
    newcls = new Object();
    newcls.Link = class_schedule.LMSURL; // Error at this line.. 
}
```

}

Error Log :

```
TID: [0]  [ESB]  [2014-10-24 14:19:45,541] ERROR -  The script engine returned an error executing the external js script : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/repository/esb/js/functions.js'} function transformPayload {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1 (<Unknown source>#53) in <Unknown source> at line number 53
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invokeMethod(RhinoScriptEngine.java:259)
```

Thanks
Kranthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the given scenario that issue will be occur with self closing tags(As you described).In the case of self closing tags it returns the value as null.Workaround for this to check the value in the js mediator and handle the null value in the case of the self closing tags.

You can use the following js function to set the value in such a scenario within the js mediator.

```
function assignValuesWithNull(value){
     var returnValue;
     if(!value){
        returnValue='';
     }
     else{
        returnValue=value;
     }
     return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use script mediator to change XML to JSON? what you have to do is , set content-type properly to get required format response.

Comment: Ratha, My original requirement was the following..We are having a challenge in trying to modify the JSON response from the output sequence. 
Have a Instructor object in the response which can occur 0 , 1 or multiple times. 

The JSON response is not consistent when it sends back the payload. 

If there is no Instructor object it doesn't send the object at all in the response 
 
If there is one Instructor object it sends it as an object 
If there are more than one Instructor objects, it sends them as an array 
We want the ESB to send the response always as an array to be consistent.